# Shortest path between 2 nodes in DAG unweighed

Tags: c++, graph, shortest-path

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define MAX_NODES 1005
#define INFINITE 
using namespace std;

vector<int> graph[MAX_NODES];
int numOfVertices, numOfEdges;

int shortest_path[MAX_NODES][MAX_NODES]; // shortest_path[i][j] holds the shortest path between i and j

int k;

int shortestPath(int i, int j) {
    // k ++;
    if (i == j) 
        shortest_path[i][j] = 1;

    // if we didn't solve shortest_path between i and j before

        // than solve it
    if (!shortest_path[i][j]) {

        int min_path = 10e6;
        for (auto vertice : graph[i])
            min_path = min(min_path, shortestPath(vertice, j) + 1);


        shortest_path[i][j] = min_path;
    }
    return shortest_path[i][j];
}

// the graph will be directed
void read() {
    int x, y; // temporary variables to read vertices and store them in our "graph"
    cin >> numOfVertices >> numOfEdges;

    for (int i = 0;i < numOfEdges;i ++) {
        cin >> x >> y;
        graph[x].push_back(y);
    }
}

void print() {
    for (int i = 0;i < numOfVertices;i ++) {
        if (graph[i].size())
            cout << i << " : ";
        for (int j = 0;j < graph[i].size();j ++) {
            cout << graph[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        if (graph[i].size())
            cout << '\n';
    }
}


int main() {
    freopen("input.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.out", "w", stdout);

    // ios_base :: sync_with_stdio(false);
    // cin.tie(NULL);
    // cout.tie(NULL);

    read();
    // print();

    int i = 1;
    int j = 7;
    int answer = shortestPath(i, j);

    if (answer == 10e6)
        printf("There are no paths between vertice %d and vertice %d\n", i, j);
    else
        printf("Shortest path between vertice %d and vertice %d ins: %d\n", i, j, answer - 1);

    // cout << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above program calculates the shortest path between 2 vertices in an unweighed DAG.

> shortest_path[i][j] = shortest path between vertice i and vertice j.

What's the complexity of the function `int shortestPath(int i, int j)` ?

I think is O(V + E) where V is number of vertices and E number of edges but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `j` is not changing in function call so the complexity of the function depends only on `i`.

`shortest_path[i][j] = min_path` is accomplishing two things: saving the minimum path from `i` to `j` and marking `i` visited (since j is not changing). Hence a vertex once visited will not be visited again.

So `shortest_path` will be called for the different values `i` can take let's call it `N` which is the total number of vertices in the graph. Therefore the minimum time complexity will be atleast `O(N)`. Inside each call, the for loop runs for `outdegree of vertex i`. Now adding the for loop costs of all vertices, it will be `outdegree of V1 + outdegree of V2 + ... + outdegree of Vn` which equals `O(E)`. Hence total time complexity is `O(N + E)`

Comment: What do you think would be my function complexity without memoization ?

Answer (score 0):

If we don't count calls where the distance of the current node has already been computed, clearly there are at most `V` function calls. The complexity of a function call ignoring the recursive calls is linear with respect to the number of neighbors of the node, so the total complexity of these calls is `O(E)`.

For the calls where the distance of the current node has already been computed, a constant number of these calls happen for each edge in the graph so the complexity is `O(E)`. This gives a combined complexity of `O(E)`.

Although the complexity of the function call is `O(E)`, your `shortest_path` array has `V^2` elements so creating the array alone is `O(V^2)`.